# scala get instance of runtime class

Tags: scala, reflection, casting

I am trying to get the instance of `runtimeClass` from `Class[_]` in scala. This is going to happen before I create my jar app.

**1) Here's my simple example using old java way** where I'm trying to get instance of `StringBuilder`. (*In my actual codebase it would be some classes extending a `trait EventProcessor`*)

```
scala> val clazz = Class.forName("scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder")
clazz: Class[_] = class scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder

scala> clazz.newInstance().asInstanceOf[StringBuilder].append("updating stuffs")
res1: StringBuilder = updating stuffs
```

**2) Another approach I can use is `isAssisgnableFrom`,**

```
scala> val clazz = Class.forName("scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder")
clazz: Class[_] = class scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder

scala> if(clazz.isAssignableFrom(classOf[StringBuilder])) clazz.newInstance.asInstanceOf[StringBuilder].append("some default data") 
       else throw new Exception(s"$clazz is not what i want")
res2: StringBuilder = some default data
```

**3) But I am attempting to get the `runtimeClass`** instead and get the instance if the right type if not fail fast.

I found hundreds of posts on scala `ClassTag[_]` but could not make it work how I want to. Maybe `asInstanceOf[T]` is best approach for what I want.

One example using `ClassTag`, where I still have to do `asInstanceOf[T]`. If so what is the advantage over old `asInstanceOf[T]`.

```
scala> ClassTag[StringBuilder](Class.forName("scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder"))
res2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[StringBuilder] = scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder

scala> res2.runtimeClass.newInstance.asInstanceOf[StringBuilder].append("update state")
res3: StringBuilder = update state
```

Also misleading thing above is that I can provide wrong Type to ClassTag as below,

```
scala> ClassTag[Int](Class.forName("scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder")).runtimeClass
res4: Class[_] = class scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder
```

**My question is what is a recommended approach to get the instance of `runtimeClass` in scala?**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the class *by name*, just go with your preferred of first two approaches.

`ClassTag`s don't provide anything useful for this, and they aren't supposed to. In particular, `ClassTag(someClass).runtimeClass` which you do in 3) will always just return `someClass`.

Comment: Yeah tried bunch of ways, `ClassTag[T]` does not seem to provide much value in this case. I might go with #2 (`isAssignableFrom `) and throw my own exception in case of  bad class-name.